# Troubleshoot 20.04 System Hang Help

Tags: kernel

So, running ubuntu 20.04.1, up to date as of today, 32 GB ram, system load typically < 1, i9-9900k not overclocked. Twice in the last month, it has hung. By hang, I mean console not responsive, no networking, nothing works, time on display stops, keyboard not functioning, etc. Nothing works, like a crash. But I can find no evidence of a crash, anywhere I should look? The 2 times this has happened, was when machine was idle (no one typing or using it, processes of course running). I have monitorix installed so can see system condition, temps, etc up to the hang time of 16:07. Nothing unusual. Temps at the crash time were around 88F (not C) on each core. System load was just under 1. Used + shared memory was 15G out of the 32G. Acpi temps were 81F reported by the MB, pch was 123F, nvidia RTX2060 temp was 99F. 2 internal HDD were 100F. Motherboard is a Gigabyte Z390 Aorus Pro WiFi. In short, great shape.

From syslog:

```
Nov 25 16:05:46 Home-Server systemd[1]: Started ZSYS daemon service.
Nov 25 16:05:46 Home-Server zsysd[2442258]: sfatula
Nov 25 16:05:46 Home-Server zsysctl[2442251]: level=error msg="couldn't save state for user \"sfatula\": Current machine isn't Zsys, nothing to create"
Nov 25 16:05:46 Home-Server systemd[6470]: zsys-user-savestate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 25 16:05:46 Home-Server systemd[6470]: zsys-user-savestate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 25 16:05:46 Home-Server systemd[6470]: Failed to start Save current user state periodically.
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Nov 25 16:39:01 Home-Server systemd-modules-load[608]: Inserted module 'lp'
Nov 25 16:39:01 Home-Server kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xde, date = 2020-05-24
```

So, time was 16:07 of the freeze as the desktop clock showed this time when I rebooted after trying all sorts of keyboard commands from console, ssh, etc.

Nothing unusual in kern.log:

```
Nov 25 14:55:19 Home-Server canonical-livepatch[5022]: No payload available.
Nov 25 15:44:44 Home-Server canonical-livepatch[5022]: Client.Check
Nov 25 15:44:44 Home-Server canonical-livepatch[5022]: Checking with livepatch service.
Nov 25 15:44:45 Home-Server canonical-livepatch[5022]: Updated last-check.
Nov 25 15:44:45 Home-Server canonical-livepatch[5022]: No updates available at this time.
Nov 25 15:44:45 Home-Server canonical-livepatch[5022]: No payload available.
Nov 25 16:39:01 Home-Server kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xde, date = 2020-05-24
Nov 25 16:39:01 Home-Server kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-54-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-54.60-generic 5.4.65)


grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

dmidecode -s bios-version
F12c

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi        12Gi        13Gi       1.2Gi       5.4Gi        17Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Poking around in other logs, I don't see anything helpful. There os nothing in /var/crash. Nothing stuck out to me in the bug database. So, not sure where to turn or look next.

18.04 didn't ever do this to me. I did not do an upgrade, fresh install as I always do, ~2 months ago or whenever it became available. Right before doing the fresh install I did a full overnight memtest just because I do when I do fresh installs. Nothing found. Also, nothing indicated in smartctl.

Any thoughts, tips, places to look, things to try?

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` to see the end of the log for the previous boot. Read `man journalctl`. If no hints are found, suspect external power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

Gigabyte Z390 Aorus Pro WiFi

You have BIOS version F12c.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F12j, dated 9/16/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Yep as mentioned, already did memtest. I did miss the f12j, so updated that last night and we'll see. As always, I set BIOS back to defaults and re-changed the settings I need. Hopefully the BIOS update will provide some positive difference.

Comment: @SteveF. Please do keep me posted!

Comment: @SteveF. Status please...

Comment: No status. Seeing if BIOS update made any difference or not. Since this only happened twice in a 30 day or so period, who's to say when it's safe to say it's resolved?

Comment: Ok, it's Jan 6 2021 and I believe BIOS update on my MB did solve the issue, no more hangs.